# Impossible to create String from char[] without copying it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, utf-8

Is there a way of creating a String from a char[] without copying it?

As you can see from the screenshots below (taken from the String class in JDK 1.8):

[image]

[image]

The constructor with which this would be possible is private and not accessible. Any workarounds maybe? Since I need the performance increase of not copying the char[].

For context: I am working on a YAML/DYML parser, where every hundredth of a millisecond is important. Here is the code (its WIP): https://github.com/Osiris-Team/Dream-Yaml/blob/main/src/main/java/com/osiris/dyml/DYReaderV2.java

Comment: No. Because `String` is immutable. You could perhaps implement `CharSequence` against the `char[]` - e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap-char:A-

Comment: But the constructor is right there? It's just not public. Which would mean that it's only immutable for us but not the JVM I guess.

Comment: @OsirisTeam Why do you think  that is? It's "the secret sauce". I can put that secret sauce on your burger, but I will never tell you how to make it. That's a package private method. Only members of `java.lang` package are privileged enough to have access to that constructor. Or, you can get the result by calling a public constructor that has access to it internally.

Comment: Also worth noting that String changes significantly in Java 9 for "compact strings". It now uses byte[] instead of char[] internally. My point is if you crack out the secret sauce you'll be building in problems for the future.

Comment: If you explain your situation fully, a proper solution can be suggested. No use getting hung up on a constructor that's not meant for you to use. How are you getting data, what are you using it for (i.e. do you need it as a `String` instead of for example a streaming solution).

Comment: String is immutable, if this constructor were made public, you can make mutable strings, which goes against the whole idea. Actually you could use reflection to invoke the constructor, but because of the reason mentioned above, that's a very bad idea.

Comment: How about creating a modified version of the JDK/JVM where that constructor is public lol.

Comment: You may want to use [CharBuffer.wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(char%5B%5D)), which will not copy the array.  And CharBuffer implements CharSequence, so you can use it in a number of places where String can be used.

Comment: What performance metrics have you taken which pinpoint this particular String constructor as your issue? It would be surprising if a change here made bigger difference than say more careful use of List, Map, database or file operations.

Comment: Since you all were so curious about the context, I just added the context to the question.

Comment: Please **DON'T** show us screen shots of your code.  Copy and paste the code into the question **as text**.

Comment: If performance is so important and you can actually proof that the copying hurts you, then maybe don't create `String` objects unless you absolutely need to. You can work with raw `char[]`, a `CharBuffer` (as mentioned  before) or use some other `CharSequence` that doesn't provide immutability but also doesn't require copying. Then you only create `String` objects when you absolutely need to (for example to return it from a method call to client code). Also: what Stephen said: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Regarding the "modified JVM": you *could* probably do that but a.) it's probably not easy, you need a good understanding of at least some JVM internals, b.) it's likely to make upgrading to another JVM version exponentially harder and c.) at that point you're not really writing "Java code" any more, if your code doesn't run on a standard JVM with all the disadvantages that has (for example new developers on your team will have a much steeper learning curve).

Comment: You are claiming that _"every hundredth of a millisecond is important"_, yet you also make clear that your code is still a work in progress! You are wasting time by looking at this issue now, without even knowing that it is going to cause a problem. Focus on getting your code past the WIP stage first. I also find it odd that you are being very shy about sharing any metrics you have for `String` creation - show us how expensive you think it is.

Comment: @skomisa it just seems logical to me that creating a string by copying the array first is more performance demanding than creating a string without copying the array first

Comment: Your code contains `new BufferedReader` which is more likely performance cause. By the way you also double copy char arrays when making strings - `new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(line, indexStart, lineIndex))` should be `new String(line, indexStart, lineIndex-indexStart)`, and create a lot of mostly unnecessary SmartString wrappers per string but I doubt fixing these would be noticable even though it cuts down on memory used.

Comment: I meant file IO in place of `new BufferedReader` above

Comment: @OsirisTeam In the absence of any metrics to demonstrate that you actually have a real world problem, your question is off topic on SO for two reasons: [1] _"there is no actual problem to be solved..."_ [2] _"you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question..."_. Please see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because _"there is no actual problem to be solved..."_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the answer is no, which is a bummer.

There are however some workarounds that are **not** reasonable:

- Make the private String constructor public via Javas reflection API
- Create a custom JVM distro with the private constructor changed to public

More reasonable alternatives would be:

- Working directly with the char[]
- Using a CharSequence or CharBuffer instead

Thanks for all the help in the comments.